How to easily bring back openSUSE logo during boot?
Currently the default behaviour is that during boot process, the computer logo manufacturer is displayed and below small system logo.
Is there a replacement package available, or magic option, to bring back the old behavior -- i.e. full screen openSUSE logo? Given how great openSUSE art is it would be perfect to have something ready to use.
I followed Is it possible to configure GRUB to remove UEFI vendor logo faster during boot? to at least disable vendor logo, but this is only partial solution for me.
